# Загрузка страницы с другого домена

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Здравствуйте! Будьте добры, подскажите, как это называется и по какому принципу оно работает.

Я об том, когда на каком-то сайте берёшь javascript код и вставляешь на свой сайт, а этот код подгружает какую-то форму, кусок страницы и т.д. С помощью JQUERY это делается и чем? Общий принцип, как мне сделать свой код, чтобы при его размещении на любом сайте выводилась нужная мне инфа. Ну типа ".load", но чтобы грузила с другого домена?

Answer (score 4):

Итак, предположим, мы пишем UserJS для домена domain.ru, который хочет сделать асинхронный запрос к веб-сервису на домене ws.org. Запросы к веб-сервису будет посылать UserJS, запущенный в iframe'е для документа с домена ws.org (допустим, ws.org/dummy.gif: какой конкретно URL — не важно). А для передачи аргументов запроса необходимо заранее, до того как откроется страничка с удаленного домена, установить window.name у фрейма в строку, содержащую эти параметры. Таким образом, UserJS на ws.org получит аргументы запроса из своего window.name и оправит необходимый XMLHttpRequest к ws.org. Ему уже можно: запрос в пределах домена ws.org. Затем результат выполнения засовывается снова в window.name фрейма, и фрейм редиректится на любую страничку на domain.ru (например, domain.ru/dummy2.gif), где снова выполняется UserJS, который запускает обработчик результата запроса в главном окне.
 Разумеется, надо выбирать документы dummy.gif и dummy2.gif, у которых установлены правильные кеширующие заголовки, потому что каждый запрос проходит через них.

На схеме это выглядит примерно так:
[image]

[Так сделал автор данной статьи на хабре(скробблер lastfm для контакта)](http://pastebin.com/f1d71b18b)

[Исходная статья](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/55825/)

Comment: а можно уже конкретный реализованный пример на исходниках посмотреть???

Comment: Вот, нашёл вам полную [инструкцию](http://javascript.ru/ajax/cross-domain-scripting).